# concurrently changing value of textView When value change from database in android

Tags: android

I want to change automatically textView data which parsed from database in android. Can I use push notification for this? How can I use it?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you insert new values in database, just get new values and set in textview again at that moment.

Comment: I want to get it automatically. I don't want to press button to refresh activity

Comment: don't press button, just set text again whenever you update new values